# Reason: Incompatible library version: identify requires version 14.0.0 or later, but libfreetype.6.dylib provides version 13.0.0 Trace/BPT trap

Tags: imagemagick, osx-snow-leopard, spree, dyld, identify

i am running 10.6.8 MacOSX Snow Leopard , and i have installed imagemagick using `brew install imagemagick` and when i run `identify` in my terminal i get the following error
I got this error when i ran `spree install` as well , as spree also uses imagemagick and imagemagick requires some dyld library version 14.0.0

## error

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/X11/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/identify
  Reason: Incompatible library version: identify requires version 14.0.0 or later, but libfreetype.6.dylib provides version 13.0.0
Reason: Incompatible library version: identify requires version 14.0.0 or later, but libfreetype.6.dylib provides version 13.0.0
Trace/BPT trap
```

I had also run software update but it does not update the DYLD Library version , How am i supposed to update the Library version from 13.0.0 to 14.0.0 or above in Snow Leopard ?Please help , thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i figured it out , if was quite simple
i just copied a different version of libfreetype.6.dyld from my MAMP installation to my /usr/X11/lib

```
sudo cp /Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib /usr/X11/lib/
```

and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing dlib library using following command

*conda install -c conda-forge dlib*

It will take care all the dependencies and eventually will work out.

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you @Vaibhav